# Laravel 5.2 Class Load Error on Development Server

Tags: php, laravel-5

So I had this application on my localhost that was running perfectly fine. However after I deployed onto the development server, I guess the Class Loader wasn't loading a third party class properly.

```
ErrorException in ClassLoader.php line 412:
include(/www/message360.com/webrtc-dev/vendor/composer/../../app/libs/message360/library/message360.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
in ClassLoader.php line 412
at HandleExceptions->handleError('2', 'include(/www/message360.com/webrtc-dev/vendor/composer/../../app/libs/message360/library/message360.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory', '/www/message360.com/webrtc-dev/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php', '412', array('file' => '/www/message360.com/webrtc-dev/vendor/composer/../../app/libs/message360/library/message360.php')) in ClassLoader.php line 412
at include() in ClassLoader.php line 412
```

Does anyone know why its coming out like this?

I am importing the class in a Users Controller

```
use Message360API\Lib\Message360;
```

The files for the third party class are location in:

```
/www/message360.com/webrtc-dev/app/Libs/message360/library
```

Comment: Check logs (Laravel has built-in Monolog library). If Laravel is initialized, fix logged exceptions. If not, check Apache (or nginx) logs. Maybe your server has different specification than your local machine (mysql version, php version, another services like Redis).

Comment: Keep in mind server 500 errors come from Apache, not PHP, in fact they are generated before the PHP interpreter is even launched. They mean "server is mis-configured"  and are usually caused by .htaccess files with typos, or using Apache v1.x syntax on a server with Apache v2.x.. or vice-versa

Comment: I think it has to do something with angular and passing a CSRF_TOKEN?

Comment: UPDATE: nevermind.. I guess a class isn't loading. I'm using an third party library and importing that class into one of my controller methods but apparently its not loading it properly on the development server.

Comment: try to Run this command in terminal, `composer dump-autoload` this will refresh your class listing.